# Hiding Subform Column in Ms-Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2003

Is it possible to hide subform column using the column number?

```
Forms("MyForm").Form("SubForm").columns(1).hidden = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
Forms("MyForm")("NameOfSubFormControl").Form.Controls(1).Visible = False
```

Comment: Tried it but shows Run Time Error 2465. Application Defined Or Object Defined Error Occurs.

Comment: Right. It is the Controls collection to use. See edited answer, please.